# can you specify the next thread to execute?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm using c++ and was just curious if I could specify which thread I want to execute next. I'm overwriting a couple of the pthread_mutex functions in order to set the order of execution in a multithreaded program.

Comment: Threads run in parallel, what do you mean by next thread to execute? You mean next thread to enter a critical section?

Comment: @leo They *may* (but don't have to) run in parallel, they just run concurrently. But yeah, OP's wording betrays great confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify directly which thread to execute, it's job of the system scheduler.

You can create a task queue, every thread blocks in the task queue. When the task have some tasks,you can notify the thread to execute by synchronization primitives.Such as ,the pthread_cond_t.